# Draw Bezier curves in the CompactFramework

Tags: c#, compact-framework

In the full .NET version, `Graphics.DrawBeziers` can be used to draw a series of cubic Bezier curves. [According to this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ds101091(v=vs.90).aspx), this is not available in the .NET CompactFramework (both v2.0 and v3.5). Can Bezier curves be drawn "from scratch" in the CompactFramework (or P/Invoked)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [excellent CodeProject article](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/25237/bezier-curves-made-simple) describes how to generate the Bezier curves from first principles. Stumbled upon the article some time after asking the question.